# Is it possible to temporarily postpane displaying an AppBarButton's affiliated Flyout?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async, flyout, winrt-component

I've got a Flyout embedded within an AppBarButton like so:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="appbarbtnOpenPhotosets" Icon="OpenFile" Label="Open Existing Photoset[s]" AutomationProperties.Name="Open File" Tapped="appbarbtnOpenPhotosets_Tapped" >
    <Button.Flyout>
    . . .
    </Button.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

I want to, under certain circumstances, first present the user with an opportunity to rename a file prior to seeing the Flyout. I tried seeing if that would work like this:

```
async private void appbarbtnOpenPhotosets_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // Want to conditionally postpone the operation
    bool myBucketsGotAHoleInIt = PhotraxUtils.GetLocalSetting(CAINT_BUY_NO_BEER);
    if (myBucketsGotAHoleInIt)
    {
        MessageDialog dlgDone = new MessageDialog("Can you see me now?");
        await dlgDone.ShowAsync();
        args.Handled = false; // <= adding this made no difference
    }
}
```

This works, in that I see the "Can you see me now?" dialog, but that prevents the Flyout from flying out. A Flyout that doesn't fly out is no more useful than a flying squirrel or fish that doesn't motate through the air.

So how can I temporarily suppress my flyout but then call it forth? The Flyout does not have an Open() method...Is there some other way to invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyouts attached to Buttons open automatically when you click the control.
If you don't want it to open automatically, you need to attach it to another control.

Example taken from [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx#using_a_flyout_with_other_ui_elements):

```
<!-- Flyout declared inline on a FrameworkElement -->
<TextBlock>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
        <!-- Flyout content -->
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

Then you can show the Flyout whenever you want, calling `FlayoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout()` and passing the FrameworkElement casted value of your control.

```
FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(frameworkElement);
```

So, in your case:

```
async private void appbarbtnOpenPhotosets_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // Want to conditionally postpone the operation
    bool myBucketsGotAHoleInIt = PhotraxUtils.GetLocalSetting(CAINT_BUY_NO_BEER);
    if (myBucketsGotAHoleInIt)
    {
        MessageDialog dlgDone = new MessageDialog("Can you see me now?");
        await dlgDone.ShowAsync();
        // New code
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
    }
}
```

If you can't change the control, you should able to use the code I posted with `Button`instead of `TextBlock`. I'm not sure about this, but you can try.